# What is the best way to make html button with link behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

I have table which has about 50 rows. Each row has link, but I need replace this link by button. And I have a few way to do this but I don't know which way is the best.

First way:

```
<form method="POST" action="some url">
   <input type="submit" value="Clickable Button">
</form>
```

Second way:

```
<input type="button" value="Action button"
onclick="window.location='http://www.w3schools.com'" />
```

Third way:

```
<input type="button" class="actionButton" value="Action button"
data-link="http://www.w3schools.com"/>
```

And after I will add javascript code with jQuery:

```
$("input.actionButton").click(function () {
   window.location = $(this).attr("data-link");
});
```

So, what is the best way?

Comment: Not sure: do you want to POST the clicked button's value to a single script? Or send the value of the clicked button via query string? Or send the user to one of multiple urls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of those three, I'd go with a `form` although if each link goes a different place, that's a lot of forms just to replicate link functionality.

But I have a fourth option for you: Style the link rather than replacing it. You can make the link look just about any way you want to, including almost entirely like a button. Since it *is* a link, that would be the most semantically-correct option (and less convoluted markup). Obviously, though, this depends on what the reason is that you have to replace the link with a button — e.g., if there's some functional, rather than appearance, requirement for doing it.

Comment: I agree, if you're using a button just because you want it to look like a button, I'd definitely recommend going back to using a link and styling the link to look like a button.

Answer (score 3):

Using a form seems the most semantically correct way. In addition to that it does not require any javascript. I would go the first way. You could include hidden fields to this form to pass additional values to the server.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a link which is supposed to look like a button, I would use an `<a>` tag styled to look like a button:

```css
/* See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html and search for system fonts */
/* See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system and search for system colors */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  font: small-caption;
  color: buttontext;
  background-color: buttonface;
  border: 2px outset buttonface;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" class="button">View</a>
  <a href="#" class="button">Cancel</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, that the first way is the most semantically correct and the one without any JavaScript, but, still, I would go the second or third way (depending on whether you also need jQuery somewhere else). By having a function there, you could put more functionality than just redirecting there. I don't know, if you might face the requirement of having additional functionality there, but so you could keep this possibility open.